# Writing a GUI to manipulate the variables in a Python program and then run the Program

Tags: java, python, user-interface, genome

So I have a gui that I'm working on (http://pastebin.com/0fPLHyHw) that I want to manipulate a program in Python that I don't quite understand (http://pastebin.com/uruxJXLx). But basically what I want to have the GUI choose the input file (e.g. a .fasta or .fa file, generally what comes out as a sequenced genome), then choose which of the DNA motifs that I want it to run the program through that file on(from the indexes of the Python program), and then run the program through that file searching for that motif and display the output that would be shown through running the Python program normally.

The thing is, I don't know an ounce of Python, so I really have NO idea how to integrate this Python program into java.

But basically I have no idea how to integrate the other files into this Java program..

Any help?

Comment: Have you considered doing this with [Biojava RestrictionEnzyme](http://www.biojava.org/docs/api1.8/org/biojava/bio/molbio/RestrictionEnzyme.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not execute your python program like you were executing it via command-line (with the parameters chosen via the GUI) from your Java program? It doesn't sound like you need any runtime interaction between the programs.

Comment: Really? I had no idea how to do that. How could I do that?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)